# Arrangements of 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6 greater than 3,000,000

Tags: combinatorics

How many numbers greater than 3,000,000 can be formed by arrangements of 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 6, 6?

Any approach on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: You have only seven digits available, and $3,000,000$ is already a seven-digit number, so you’ll have to use all seven digits.

- There are only two possibilities for the first digit; what are they?
- Note that every seven-digit number that you can form with one of those first digits will be large enough. For each of the two possible first digits, calculate the number of distinct ways of arranging the other $6$ digits.

Comment: Is 840 correct?

Comment: @gandolf: I get quite a bit less than that. With first digit $4$ I count $\frac{6!}{3!2!}=60$, and with first digit $6$ I count $\frac{6!}{2!2!}=180$, for a total of only $240$.

Comment: Yeah, your're right. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @gandolf: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The first digit is $4$ or $6$. Others can be chosen independently.